# Java JPasswordField .getPassword() issues

Tags: java, user-interface, jpasswordfield

I'm using the JPasswordField to have a username and a password for a login feature. The .getPassword works for the password, but not for the username. Any idea why it is not working for the username if I typed the same exact thing?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class pros
{
    JFrame frame;
    private static void show(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("LOGIN");
    frame.setSize(450,450);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JLabel username = new JLabel("Enter the Username: ",JLabel.LEFT);
    username.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    username.setFont(username.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
    panel.add(username);

    JPasswordField user = new JPasswordField(10);
    user.setEchoChar('?');
    panel.add(user);

    JLabel password = new JLabel("Enter your Password: ",JLabel.RIGHT);
    password.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    password.setFont(password.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
    panel.add(user);
    panel.add(password);

    JPasswordField field = new JPasswordField(10);
    field.setEchoChar('•');

    JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            String input = String.valueOf(field.getPassword());
            String user = String.valueOf(user.getPassword());
            if(input.equals("double" && user.equals("relocating")))
            {
                field.setText("");
               pane();
        }
    }});
    panel.add(field);
    panel.add(ok);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
    System.out.println(input+"  "+user)
before the if statement just to see what are the values of the variable then you will know the problem and you can fix it

```
{
        String input = String.valueOf(field.getPassword());
        String user = String.valueOf(user.getPassword());
        System.out.println(input+"  "+user);//here print see the consul to know why it's not working
        if(input.equals("double" && user.equals("relocating")))
        {
            field.setText("");
           pane();
    }
```

or may be because you are using the same name for the string and the field

Comment: or may be because you are using the same name for the string and the field

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in you code. First of all you add the 'user' JPasswordField twice in you parent panel. First time is done here:

```
JPasswordField user = new JPasswordField(10);
user.setEchoChar('?');
panel.add(user);
```

After you initialize the component and one here:

```
JLabel password = new JLabel("Enter your Password: ",JLabel.RIGHT);
password.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
password.setFont(password.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
panel.add(user);
panel.add(password);
```

Secondly, why you add your component to the panel 'field' after the initialization of the button (along with it's listener).

Thirdly, how long is your username? If it longer than 10 characters I would not work since you have limited the size.